# How can I get the user's name when using Oauth facebook with Phoenix?

Tags: oauth, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Oauth with facebook, and when I log in, I'd like to redirect to a page that is called "localhost:4000/#{users_name}" but I don't know how to find that within the data I'm getting when logging in. Here is the data I am getting back:

```
%Ueberauth.Auth{credentials: %Ueberauth.Auth.Credentials{expires: true, expires_at: 1499387613, other: %{}, refresh_token: nil, scopes: [""], secret: nil, token: "EAALqHWlJR50BAJYqHNIxcwLB9ayK2yzzaZBVqNHgLeAxz4MOoMaPGYGaiz0c1ZBHanIZB2f5ojVRQnFcqdeGxQpkar7CybjrnhzuKc0uYamEUbjwrjhARZCAxVu28E1LtyILEMheb6cc90ZAHVHgctmwL4GIC9AsZD", token_type: nil}, extra: %Ueberauth.Auth.Extra{raw_info: %{token: %OAuth2.AccessToken{access_token: "EAALqHWlJR50BAJYqHNIxcwLB9ayK2yzzaZBVqNHgLeAxz4MOoMaPGYGaiz0c1ZBHanIZB2f5ojVRQnFcqdeGxQpkar7CybjrnhzuKc0uYamEUbjwrjhARZCAxVu28E1LtyILEMheb6cc90ZAHVHgctmwL4GIC9AsZD", expires_at: 1499387613, other_params: %{}, refresh_token: nil, token_type: "Bearer"}, user: %{"id" => "1650030525022203", "name" => "Moe Chughtai"}}}, info: %Ueberauth.Auth.Info{description: nil, email: nil, first_name: nil, image: "http://graph.facebook.com/1650030525022203/picture?type=square", last_name: nil, location: nil, name: "Moe Chughtai", nickname: nil, phone: nil, urls: %{facebook: nil, website: nil}}, provider: :facebook, strategy: Ueberauth.Strategy.Facebook, uid: "1650030525022203"}
```